# jquery allow dots only with numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following function which allows only numbers on keypress:

```
$('input').keypress(function(e) {
var a = [];
var k = e.which;

for (i = 48; i < 58; i++)
    a.push(i);

if (!($.inArray(k,a)>=0))
    e.preventDefault();
});​
```

I am unable to also allow dots (code: 190). Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/umNuB/

Comment: Beware that you've also successfully disabled backspace and delete.

Comment: As someone else noted - the decimal value for "dots" (.) is 46 - not 190 - see: http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm

Comment: The dot actually has code 46.

Comment: Typo sorry, updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add

```
a.push(46);
```

after your loop and it will allow periods.

Answer (score 1):

I think u want to validate input only float number allowed, here the sample float validate

```
$('input').keypress(function(event) {
  if ((event.which != 46 || $(this).val().indexOf('.') != -1) && (event.which < 48 || event.which > 57)) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

On my own keyboard `e.which` for `.` is `46`; where did you get `190` from? Therefore my code would be:

```
$('input').keypress(function(e) {
    var a = [46];
    var k = e.which;
    for (i = 48; i < 58; i++)
        a.push(i);

    if (!($.inArray(k,a)>=0))
        e.preventDefault();
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/umNuB/357/)